# What does diffeomorphism say about volume?

Tags: differential-geometry

What does there being a diffeomorphism between two sets (that have volumes) say about volumes?

I read somewhere about "volume forms" perhaps being preserved under diffeomorphisms.

Does this mean that the volumes of two diffeomorphically related sets are the same?
 Or are they related?
What does it mean?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. Requiring that a diffeomorphism send a particular volume form to another particular volume form is an extra condition.

Comment: The condition of _being_ a volume form--- that is, being a nowhere-vanishing form--- is preserved under diffeomorphism. There are many such forms, though, and diffeomorphisms don't preserve a particular choice of one.

Answer (score 1):

False. Counterexample: $x\mapsto 2x$ between $(0,1)$ andd $(0,2)$.

Comment: I have few naive questions. Do we fix volume forms here? Aren't volumes the same if we put induced volume form onto $(0, 2)$ ?

Comment: The "false" is the answer to the question "Does this mean that the volumes of two diffeomorphically related sets are the same?" As anomaly has said, volume form aren't unique and diffeomorphisms send a volume form to *some* volume form.

Comment: These questions were loosely related to OP's questions, I just wanted to quickly clarify this for myself :)

Comment: @Evgeny, sorry, I v'e missed your previous commentary. In my counterexample I'm supposing that the volume forms give vol(0,1) = 1 and vol(0,2) = 2 ($dx$ in both sides). Obviously, if we define vol in (0,2) as vol of the inverse image, both sets have the same volume.

Comment: So, in case of induced volume form it is just a consequence of definition, right? Thank you very much :)